# How to solve HadoopFsRelationProvider in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using spark 2.0.2 ,scala 2.11.7
When I'm running spark standalone cluster ,I found in master webui the output in completed application .on the other hand ,I found  this error

```
SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/salma/Movielens/spark-warehouse'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelationProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

How to solve it?